Why does the ZX Spectrum ROM set I register, then wait 24 T-states?
I’m doing some low-level, interrupt-based Z80 Spectrum programming, and, investigating the ROM, found this oddity (clipped from The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly), in the ROM initialisation/startup code, just before the RAM test:

I have two questions:

Given that the Spectrum ROM sets Interrupt Mode 1, why does it set the value of I?

IM 1 causes the (vertical blanking) interrupt on the Spectrum to call location 0x38, and does not (AFAIK) involve the I register at all.
0x3F doesn’t… relate to anything. Does it? There’s no instruction at that location, I think.


The comment/analysis for the six DEFB +00/NOP says “Wait 24 T states”. Indeed, that’s what 6 NOPs do, but why?

This is just before the RAM-CHECK routine, so does it have some effect on that?



Am I missing something? Or is it just the Spectrum ROM being quirky?

I’ve had a look at the ZX81 ROM, and it sets the I register to 0x1E, because that register is used as part of the ZX81 character-generation circuitry. This would not apply to the Spectrum.

The code that follows this may be needing an interrupt to have happened before execution.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, Reasonable guess, except that: 24 t-states is not long enough to wait (for the vertical blank interrupt) — and, at this point in the startup sequence, interrupts are disabled :)

Well, the question did not indicate you knew this.

Very glad you asked this, I wondered the same in 1984 when learning practical programming from so many reads of this whole ROM listing. Upvoted.

The discussion of the prototype ROM at https://spectrumforeveryone.com/technical/inside-the-prototype-zx-spectrums-rom/ calls the six NOPs a "warm-up delay" - possibly the CPU powered up slightly faster than the RAM and a short delay was needed before the memory test could be done. Or perhaps the NOPs were so that the developer could quickly patch in changes at that point while debugging, without having to reassemble the entire ROM.

From the "16k / 48k Spectrum Reference" document at World of Spectrum:

Finally, there is an interesting bug in the ULA which also has to do
with this split bus. After each instruction fetch cycle of the
processor, the processor puts the I-R register "pair" (not the 8 bit
internal Instruction Register, but the Interrupt and R registers) on
the address bus. The lowest 7 bits, the R register, are used for
memory refresh. However, the ULA gets confused if I is in the range
64-127, because it thinks the processor wants to read from lower 16K
RAM very, very often. The ULA can't cope with this read-frequency, and
regularly misses a screen byte. Instead of the actual byte, the byte
previously read is used to build up the video signal. The screen seems
to be filled with 'snow'; however, the Spectrum won't crash, and
program will continue to run normally.

The startup code in the ROM therefore has to make sure I is not pointing at the lower 16k of RAM. Pointing it at the ROM accomplishes this.

Brilliant, that answers the first part!
Any idea about the "24 wait states"? (I’m inclined to mark as "accepted" and raise another question?)

@andrewf The NOPs might be connected to setting the I register, so you might want to wait some time before splitting your question.

I wonder why the ROM’s authors didn’t just do:
XOR A; LD I,A …unless to make that "less than $40" more explicit.

@andrewf: In IM2, the interrupt routine jumps to the address contained at the word at address I*256+255 (or whatever is on the data bus at the time), and by setting it to $3F, it'll point to an area filled with $FF, leading it to jump to address $FFFF where you'd normally put a JR byte (can't remember opcode) which would then - combined with the opcode for the first byte in the ROM - a DI - would lead to a relative jump some bytes backward in memory, where you would then place an absolute JP to your interrupt routine. Perhaps the author thought of this when he decided to use $3F.

@HeartWare, That crossed my mind too, but the 257 0xFFs are at 0x3800, not 0x3F00, so it would need to put 0x38 into I not `0x3F. http://www.breakintoprogram.co.uk/hardware/computers/zx-spectrum/interrupts
(Not to mention the fact that the ROM uses IM 1, not IM 2.)
